# Position two div next to each other inside a parent DIV

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have two DIVs inside another two parent DIVs. What I am looking to do is align the "clocks" DIV to the left of the "panel" DIV and the "sd" DIV toward the center of the "panel" DIV.

What is showing up as now:
[image: What I see now]

What I am looking to do:
[image: desired image]

My HTML looks like:

```
<div id="weather">
    <div id="panel">
        <div class="clocks">
        </div>
        <div id="sd">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.weathers.com"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="slide"><a href="#" class="btn-slide">Weather</a></p>
</div>
```

My CSS looks like:

```
#weather {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 990px;
    font: 75%/120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999999999;
    left: 0%;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#panel {
    background: url('weatherBack.png') no-repeat;
    height: 195px;
    width: 990px;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 195px;
}
#sd {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 175px;
}
.slide {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: solid 4px #422410;
    background: url(btn.png) no-repeat center top;
}
.btn-slide {
    background: url(white-arrow.gif) no-repeat right -50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 144px;
    height: 31px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    font: bold 120%/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.active {
    background-position: right 12px;
}
.learn {
    z-index: 9999999999999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    right: 3px;
}
.box-cnt {
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    background-color: #1FAAEB;
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.clocks {
    width: 209px;
    height: 131px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 151;
    background: url('css/images/clockbg.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a live link that I can troubleshoot with?

Comment: Have a look at CSS floats. That or absolute positioning.

Comment: Hint: position:relative is used when you have absolutely-positioned child elements. You don't have and, so don't use this.

Comment: http://www.interfaithmedical.com/Portal/indextest.htm please check the link and let me know how to resolve.

Comment: @Michael: http://www.interfaithmedical.com/Portal/indextest.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try the `float` property with a value of `left` on your clock and weather panels:

```css
.clocks {
    width: 209px;
    height: 131px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: url('css/images/clockbg.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}

#sd {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 175px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is a working JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/cYFfT/

If you want to have more space between them, simply set a left margin on the SD panel,
as in this update: http://jsfiddle.net/cYFfT/1/

Comment: They both appear on the left.

Comment: @SiKni8 I put `float:left;` on the SD div and already it was positioned correctly..

Comment: @Mario... did you take a look at the link I included? :)

Comment: @SiKni8 I did, and at least in the latest firefox it looks good... if you put `float:left;` on the SD div.